# How to sort number in a row?

Tags: csv, sorting

Could somebody please help me how to sort numbers in a row divided by delimiter? I would like to use sort or awk, but I am not familiar with them

cat values.csv:

```
36;21;9;32;16;48
47;2;44;17;26;32
44;2;24;43;20;33
13;6;42;12;19;28
10;3;34;30;35;40
35;22;17;28;24;23
```

I expect these values:

```
9;16;21;32;36;48
2;17;26;32;44;47
2;20;24;33;43;44
6;12;13;19;28;42
3;10;30;34;35;40
17;22;23;24;28;35
```

Comment: Since you did not even mention any technology you want to use, I can only assume that you want to print it on a piece of paper, cut that into rows, and then sort them … so, what exact problem are you having with this rather elementary school-level task …? // Seriously, please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly!

Comment: Hello really sorry for that. I created this task under time pressure :( I will edit it..

Answer (score 0):

Ok i did it :)

As firt via sed substitue ; for ,

a then:

```
while read line; do 
    tr , $'\n' < <(printf -- "%s" "$line") | sort -g | tr $'\n' , | sed 's/,$/\n/';
done < values.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('values.csv', 'r') as file:
   for line in file.read():
      print(sorted(list(map(int, line))))
```

Here we go first you read the file line by line then 
split and make all of the items integers and sort them VOILA